# Short forms for function-parameter combinations?

Tags: functions, options

I find these to be very convenient, particularly since I use the base-10 log fairly frequently:

- `Log[2, n]`=> `Log2@n`
- `Log[10, n]` => `Log10@n`

These represent a very specific type of syntactic sugar, in which the parameter modifying the function (in this case, the base) is subsumed into the function name.

Thus I'm wondering: Are there any other constructions like these?

These are qualitatively different from the main class of Mathematica keystroke-savers, namely the extensive set of operator short forms, such as `/@` for `Map` (see [Mathematica Operator Input Forms](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html)).  Indeed, Wolfram itself seems not to consider `Log2` and `Log10` special Operator Input Forms, since they can't be found in the latter list.

Again, I'm specifically refering to constructions in which a parameter is subsumed into a function name. In case this is still a bit unclear,  just for the purpose of illustration, consider `Drop`, and imagine that `Rest` didn't exist. It's common to use `Drop` to remove the first element of an expression, using the parameter `1`, as in `Drop[expr, 1]`. Thus a nice bit of syntactic sugar (if `Rest` didn't exist) would be if there were, say, `Drop1` to do this. I.e., `Drop1@expr` instead of `Drop[expr, 1]`.

Another hypothetical example would be if there existed, say, `FormatT` and `FormatS`  as short forms for `Format[expr, TraditionalForm]` and `Format[expr, StandardForm]`.

Note that, by contrast, `LegendreP` and `LegendreQ` don't count, because each of these is a distinct function in its own right.  I.e., there is no `Legendre` function, for which `P` and `Q` are possible parameters.

Comment: Besides the newly added `|->`, you can see a complete list in [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/77079)

Comment: @BenIzd I'm familiar with that list of operator short forms. As I explained, I'm instead looking specifically for short forms for function-value combinations

Comment: The short forms you describe are similar to what the docs call Operator Forms.  There is a (short) list of functions that have operator forms in this [Guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionCompositionAndOperatorForms.html).  Also `OperatorApplied` can be used to create operator forms.

Comment: @LouisB  No, those are qualitatively different.  I'm talking specifically about existing functions that take certain values as options, for which Wolfram has created a new combined function that incorporates that function-value combination.

Comment: @Ben Izd I tried but did not manage to find the meaning of `|->` in the documentation. Could you please kindly shortly explain, what is it and give a reference?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch It was a feature added in 12.2 (also with `//=`), it's just an easy way to type `\[Function]`. Syntax was mentioned in [Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) but as of now, I couldn't see an example in the examples section. You can see examples in the [12.2 announcement blog](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2020/12/launching-version-12-2-of-wolfram-language-mathematica-228-new-functions-and-much-more/) under the "Making Code Just a Bit More Beautiful" section.

Comment: I notice you clarified your question a bit, but do you have any examples of functions that are not `Log` that match your criteria? It seems that there may not be others like that, and that those only satisfy your criteria by chance/on a technicality.

Comment: There could be some hidden internal functions that do this. The hashes might do this though it's more of a reduction of compounded functions and a value ("Base64Encoding") into one function - e.g you can replace `StringTake[Hash["1234", "Expression", "Base64Encoding"], ;; -2]` with ```GeneralUtilities`Base64Hash["1234"]```

Comment: Note also that `Log[b, x]` is short for `Log[x]/Log[b]` (and this shows that `Log2` and `Log10` are really short for such forms and that `Log[x]/Log[2]` really has two short forms).  But at this point, if it’s merely about some code transforming into other code, I think the boundaries of what can and cannot be included will disappear.

Comment: @CATrevillian  I don't know of any others.  But it certainly looks like there are other good candidates for abbreviating common function-value combinations, so I was wondering if there were.  For quite a while I'd been using `Log[10,x]`, and always thought it was cumbersome (plus I always had to test it or look it up, since I could never remember if it was `Log[x, 10]` or `Log[10,x]`).  Thus I was chagrined to discover that there was a simple, easily-remembered shortcut I could have been using all along: `Log10`.   Consequently, I am wondering if are others like this of which I'm unaware.

Comment: @MichaelE2:  "`Log[b, x]` is short for `Log[x]/Log[b]` (and this shows that `Log2` and` Log10` are really short for such forms...."  Agreed.   ".... and that `Log[x]/Log[2]` really has two short forms".  Not following—it seems `Log[x]/Log[2]` has one short form:  `Log2`.   Also: I think there's a clear distinction between the class of functions I'm asking about, and the usual operator short forms, as indicated by the fact that Wolfram didn't include `Log2` and `Log10` on their Operator Input Form List (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html)

Comment: The two forms `Log[2, x]` and `Log2[x]` are short for `Log[x]/Log[2]`. Note that this is not true for numeric `x`: `x = 1.4;
Log2[x x] - Log[2, x]` and `Log2[xx] - Log[xx]/Log[2]`. Try it for `x = 0.9` and `x = 0.499` and see that all three are different. -- Also, I'm not talking about operator forms, but code (e.g. `Log2[x]`) that expands to other code (`Log[x]/Log[2]`).  The first is a way to get the second, and if it's shorter, we can call it a "short form."

Comment: I suppose you would include other special values of parameters like `Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, z]` being short for `HypergeometricPFQ[{a, b}, {c}, z]`? (There are a few other hypergeometric examples.)

Comment: @MichaelE2  Sure, you can come up with all sorts of definitions of long form vs. short form, such as the one you offered based on whether a longer form can be obtained using `Expand`.  But—and forgive me if I'm missing something—that doesn't seem to have anything to do with what I mean by short form, so I'm afraid I don't see the relevance here.  Again, I'm talking specifically about functions (esp. commonly-used function) that take some value as a modifier to what the function does (Wolfram calls it a "value", but that word has an overly broad meaning, so let's call it a "parameter")....

Comment: *where the syntatic sugar is that the parameter is subsumed into the funcition name.*  For instance, just for the purpose of illustration, consider `Drop`, and imagine that `Rest` didn't exist.   It's common to use `Drop` to remove the first element of an expression, using the parameter `1`, as `Drop[expr, 1]`.  Thus a nice bit of syntatic sugar (if `Rest` didn't exist) would be if there were, say, `Drop1` to do this.  I.e., `Drop1@expr instead of `Drop[expr, 1]` .  That's the kind of construction I'm talking about.

Comment: `Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, z]` is a nice convenience vs. `HypergeometricPFQ[{a, b}, {c}, z]`, though this is a different class of convenience from what I'm referring to. Here, instead of subsuming a parameter into the function name, the syntactic convenience is that you can drop a bunch of curly braces.  Also: I'm afraid I didn't follow what you were trying to say with your numerical example. Is x x =x^2, and is xx a new variable?  [N.B.: I just rewrote my OP, incorporating language I used in my comments to you; hopefully that will make it clearer.]

Comment: Would `ListLinePlot` vs. `ListPlot` count? Apart from potentially minor differences I am not aware of, the main one is that `ListLinePlot` is effectively `ListPlot` with the option `Joined->True`

Comment: @LukasLang  It wasn't quite what I had in mind, since they are slightly different functions* but, yes, effectively, that would count. [*If you don't want to bother to manually adjust the the point sizes, `ListLinePlot` gives more distinctive (larger) points than `ListPlot` w/ `Joined->True`. Compare, for instance `ListPlot[Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}], Mesh -> All, 
 Joined -> True]` with `ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}], Mesh -> All]`].

Comment: For `xx` read `x`.  That was a typo I didn't catch. -- So, for things like `FuncA[x]` being short for `Func[A, x]` or `Func[x, A]`, there are no others I believe.  For things like `ListLinePlot`, perhaps `NDSolveValue[ode, {y1, y2,...}, ...]` as short for `{y1, y2,...} /. First@NSolve[ode, {y1, y2,...},...]` (ignoring some trivial checking for more than one solution) would likewise count?

Comment: Another way to look at `Log2` is that it is an implementation of an [IEEE 754 recommendation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Recommended_operations).  Others include ``Internal`Log1p`` and ``Internal`Expm1``.  Or they could be looked as exposing some of the MKL functions.  This includes ``Internal`ReciprocalSqrt`` and ``Internal`Square``. But not ``Internal`AbsSquare``, which is in neither IEEE 754 nor MKL. Again they are not merely short forms, but separate implementations that reduce round-off error and/or improve speed.